# Parsing Dice Notation

Tags: parsers, parsing

The syntax of dice notation follows the following grammar:

$$ Roll \rightarrow Dice | Dice'x'Int | More \quad Mod \quad More $$
$$ Dice \rightarrow Int_{1}'d'Int_2$$
$$ Mod \rightarrow '+'|'-'$$
$$ More \rightarrow Int | Roll$$
$$ Int \rightarrow <integer>$$

Give a leftmost derivation for the sample string:
$3d8 + 2d4x3 + 1d12 + 567$

I was able to parse the two first operands $3d8 + 2d4x3$ but I couldn't find a reasonable derivation for the rest.

My solution is like:

```
E -> More Mod More
E -> Roll Mod More
E -> Dice Mod More
E -> Int1’d’Int2 Mod More
E -> <integer>’d’Int2 Mod More
...
...
E -> <integer>’d’<integer> + <integer>’d’<integer>’x’<integer> + More Mod More
E -> <integer>’d’<integer> + <integer>’d’<integer>’x’<integer> + Roll Mod More
E -> <integer>’d’<integer> + <integer>’d’<integer>’x’<integer> + Dice Mod More
E -> <integer>’d’<integer> + <integer>’d’<integer>’x’<integer> + Int1’d’Int2 Mod More
```

I was thinking that the given string is not a valid string for this grammar.

Does any have any idea for this problem. I'm newbie in Compiler Design :-)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Your string is of the form *Dice+Dice+Dice+Int*. Figure out how to obtain this from *Roll* using only the first, third and fourth rule.

Comment: Thank you! Actually, in the third and fourth string is `1d12 + 567` 12 and 567 is an integer, not three consecutive integers. After that clarity, everything is much easier for me.